# AndEngine Physics Box2D Extension

Tags: box2d, physics, andengine

I'm using AndEngine for my android game, I downloaded the master AndEngine from github,but there is no Physics Box2D Extension for master. I don't know where to download it or which version of it could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using nicolas' copy of AndEngine, look at his account on GitHub. All the extensions are listed under his repositories: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich

The Box2DExtension is here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

If you are like me using RealMayo's fork of AndEngine however you will have to also use his copy of the PhysicsBox2DExtension which is located here: https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

Comment: I'm using the GLES2 PhysicsBox2DExtension now,but the result of the collision isn't what I want(I think..) ,so I'd like to find a useful version of PhysicsBox2DExtension,do the extensions you mentioned above support the master Andengine well? I want my game to run on the emulator

Comment: Most implementations of GLES2 do not work on the standard emulator, you will need to debug your program on an actual device.
Other than that, I dont know what exactly you are refering to by the "master" AndEngine. Do you mean the original autor's copy (nicolas')?

Comment: It also may help if you describe the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/master                this is where I download the AndEngine, and I want to run the project on the emulator , is there any solution?

Comment: I want to know which version of the PhysicsBox2DExtension  can work well with the AndEngine I downloaded

Comment: when I use the GLES2 PhysicsBox2DExtension, for example I have two sprites that are connected with the body I create in the physicsworld,when the collision happens,the two sprites may overlap,I guess it's the problem of the PhysicsBox2DExtension,so I want to change the version of it.

Comment: I have solved my problem,it's the matter of PhysicsWorld, anyway, thanks for your answer..